# SQL: clause with newbie syntax error

Tags: sql, mysql

i have this clause:

```
"Select *
From
(
  Select sedi_i18n.*,
  0 orden
    From table sedi_i18n
   Where culture= 'italiano'
   Union
  Select sedi_i18n.*, 1 orden
    From table sedi_i18n
  Where culture<> 'italiano'  
)
Order By orden, culture";
```

But i'm getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'table sedi_i18n Where
>   culture= 'italiano' Union Select
>   sedi_i18n.*, 1 or' at line 6

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a subquery alias after your parenthesis, and to remove the word table - like so:

```
Select *
From
(
  Select sedi_i18n.*,
  0 orden
    From sedi_i18n
   Where culture= 'italiano'
   Union
  Select sedi_i18n.*, 1 orden
    From sedi_i18n
  Where culture<> 'italiano'  
) SQ
Order By orden, culture;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
0 orden
```

need to be

```
0 , orden
```

the same problem with

```
1 orden

1, orden
```

also fix @Stiivi remark

Answer (score 0):

At first sight this looks like a problem:

```
From table sedi_i18n
```

should be:

```
From sedi_i18n
```

(without the 'table' word)

Same on line 6 and line 10.

Answer (score 0):

do you require the word "table" in your statement?  I recommend taking the union out and running it without it to see what you get.  Break it down and see how where your real error is.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the word "table" in your queries. Also alias the inner query.

```
"Select *
From
(
  Select sedi_i18n.*,
  0 orden
    From sedi_i18n
   Where culture= 'italiano'
   Union
  Select sedi_i18n.*, 1 orden
    From sedi_i18n
  Where culture<> 'italiano'  
) a
Order By orden, culture";
```